# what is the android-studio way of storing configurations- key/value pairs for test/prod?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to store parameters such as admob-id, and folder path
these parameters are different for test /prod

how should I approach this in Android studio (there are properties file in the Spring framework, i'm looking for the right way for Android studio IDE )

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource (it matters into which source-set one puts the files; where test builds are by default debug builds).

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of the string resource, but didn't understand how to use source sets to differenciate production from test.  could you provide an example pls ?

Answer (score 3):

You can either use the [buildConfigField](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType:buildConfigField(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) or the [resValue](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType:resValue(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method of the [buildType](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType.html) block in the Android Gradle Plugin. The former generates global Java constants while the latter generates Android resources.

You can review the official docs showing an example of using both [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips#share-custom-fields-and-resource-values-with-your-app-code).

I'll elaborate here anyway in case it helps.

First, you define one or more config fields or res values in your `build.gradle` file. For your example for an AdMob ID, you'd define string constants.

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            buildConfigField "String", "ADMOB_ID", '"ConstantIdForRelease"'
            resValue "string", "admob_id", "StringResourceForRelease"
        }
        debug {
            buildConfigField "String", "ADMOB_ID", '"ConstantIdForDebug"'
            resValue "string", "admob_id", "StringResourceForDebug"
        }
}
```

This would generate `BuildConfig.java` and temp `generated.xml` files for both release and debug variants:

**Release:**

/app/build/generated/source/buildConfig/**release**/your/package/app/BuildConfig.java:

```
public final class BuildConfig {
    public static final String ADMOB_ID = "ConstantIdForRelease";
}
```

/app/build/generated/res/resValues/**release**/values/generated.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Values from build type: releaes -->
    <string name="admob_id" translatable="false">StringResourceForRelease</string>
</resource>
```

**Debug:**

/app/build/generated/source/buildConfig/**debug**/your/package/app/BuildConfig.java:

```
public final class BuildConfig {
    public static final String ADMOB_ID = "ConstantIdForDebug";
}
```

/app/build/generated/res/resValues/**debug**/values/generated.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Values from build type: debug -->
    <string name="admob_id" translatable="false">StringResourceForDebug</string>
</resource>
```

Then, in your code, you would just use the constant or resource like normal:

```
callMethodThatNeedsAdModId(BuildConfig.ADMOB_ID);
// OR
callMethodThatNeedsAdModId(context.getString(R.string.admob_id));
```

The actual value of the build config variable or string resource will resolve based on the current build type / variant.

Either way works, so which should you use?
If you need to access the config string in XML resources (say you want to change the `label` of an Activity in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file in debug), you'd use the resource. Otherwise, just use the build config property since you won't need a Context to access it.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

[string resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource) can be used, in combination with [source-sets](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet.html).

when defining the production values in `main` and overriding in `debug`, this should suffice.

for example:

- `src/main/res/values/strings.xml` (`main` is the default for all build types).
- `src/debug/res/values/strings.xml` (unit tests are also build-type `debug`).

these files will be merged when building; and it will override the values, where the name of a string resource matches. source-set `debug` might only have a few files, because it only has the overrides.

with AdMob, the issue merely is having different package-names, per build-type (which is not supported); recently ended up adding the alternate package-name with the `.debug` suffix, too.